# how to get 1000 number of records in phpmyadmin ui

Tags: phpmyadmin

[how to see after 500 records in phpmyadmin user interface.if any one give answer][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ktk6Y.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a table has more rows, you will see a page selector and links like ">" and ">>" on the same line as the one where you see the "Number of rows" selector.

Answer (score 0):

There is a **Show all** rows option also provided in phpmyadmin you can see that from, the first where you click on dropdown of per page record show.

Comment: Yes but "By default it is shown only on small tables (less than 500 rows) to avoid performance issues while getting too many rows."

Comment: yup,
but if you want to see all or above 500 then i m asking for the right option that show all button.